# Изменение порядка вывода данных внутри элемента

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как можно с помощью скрипта поменять порядок вывода записи?

К примеру, заменить
`<span class="amount">руб.50000</span>` на `<span class="amount">50000 руб.</span>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в начале всегда *руб.*, а затем идёт сумма, то можно так:

```js
$('.amount').text(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    return text.substr(4) + ' ' + text.substr(0, 4);
});
```

```html
<span class="amount">руб.50000</span>
<span class="amount">руб.40000</span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Работает для нескольких элементов с классом `.amount`.

Comment: эхх, но в моем случае опять это не срабатывает...хоть по функции судя по консоли проходит

Comment: @Вася всё как обычно - есть вопрос, есть ответ, дающий решение для заданного вопроса. Более того, если действительно все `.amount` имеют такой вид, то код будет работать. Если же вы выполняете этот код **до** того, как в `.amount` вообще создаются и в них пишутся данные, то чуть более чем логично разместить его **после** того, как в `.amount` добавятся значения.

Comment: к сожалению, это не выручает - видимо ajax используемый на странице это перебивает..

Comment: @Вася 1. Проверьте внимательно когда меняется и явно, и неявно (например, при success Ajax-запроса) значение в `.amount`. И используйте этот код каждый раз после изменения значения. Внимательно и осознанно. 2. Меня весьма беспокоит, что ваши вопросы делятся на те, которым вообще сложно дать ответ, и на те, которым даются **правильные** ответы на предоставленный в вопросе код, но у вас почему-то это не работает. Лишь редкие вопросы не вызывают проблем. Мне кажется, что такой подход может привести к тому, что на ваши вопросы просто перестанут отвечать.

Comment: 1. немного не понял вас - как это проверить?
2. меня это тоже очень беспокоит и как вы могли заметить всеми упорно силами пытаюсь в этом разобраться и тем самым быть полезным не только себе, но и другим. не волнуйтесь - я оцениваю все правильные и отмечаю решенные ответы

Comment: @Вася 1. Сидеть и отлаживать код. Делать `console.log()` для всего, что не приколочено. Разбираться что, когда и почему меняется у вас на странице. 2. Проблема в том, что мы сидим и гадаем. Времени на это уходит очень много, а результата - мало. Я понимаю, что у вас большой проект и куча всяких библиотек, которые насилуют HTML-код страницы как хотят, постоянно что меняя и куда-то что-то навешивая. Но так как это всё только у вас, то разобраться в этом можете только вы. Ленты по 30+ комментариев - это как-то не здорово.

Comment: @Вася кстати, а что с этим с ответом? Ответ на вопрос ведь дан.